# File Server on Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am just a beginner in HyperLedger Composer and Fabrics.

Following IBM tutorial under 'https://www.coursera.org/learn/ibm-blockchain-essentials-for-developers'

I have one quick question:

How to create a File Server using Hyperledger Composer?
Is it possible now or not?
any feedback will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Using Composer and Fabric as a File Server would be unusual, and due to the nature of Fabric as a Distributed Ledger, it may well perform badly as a File Server.

There are other Questions and Answers in Stack Overflow about storing images etc using base64 encoding, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464591/what-is-the-best-way-of-image-storage-on-hyperledger-composer).

Depending on your use case, it may be more appropriate to store some hash of the file on the Fabric enabling you to prove the validity of the file, whilst storing the file itself on a dedicated File Server.

Comment: Thank you, @r-thatcher, for your response. So you are saying only to Hash of file on Fabric and exact file on different server?

Answer (score 0):

With the nature of technology, saving a file in hyperledger fabric and using it as a file server would not be a good strategy.

You Hash the original file and Use hyperledger fabric to store the Hash value and other data you need for the system and to Validate. But you should use a different server to Store the Files.

Something similar to this would work I guess: [A Sample System Design : Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmZ7.jpg) 
[image]

Any changes, updates or a version change, you store the new file in the server, create the new hash and add the data in to new entry in hyperledger fabric.

Comment: so how it solving the problem of trust .. bcz we cannot validate the content of file server?

Comment: If you were planing to use Hyperledger based technologies to ensure trust :

Assuming the Users already understand that blockchain based technologies are proven to be incorruptible. 

Using the Original-Current File Hash, you need to build a mechanism to show the users that the Files have not been tampered with.
--1--When they Upload the File, create the Hash add it to Hyperlegdger as a Token of the Original Document
--2--Later at any given point let them compare the current files they get with the Original Hash

Comment: If you were just using the Hyperledger Fabric based technologies as a storage method : 

This question and answers will give you a better perspective. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047889/is-blockchain-a-distributed-database/49385798#49385798


Also the system design and how you market and interpret this to the Users matter when building the trust